# What are volume driver in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-volume

While doing volume mounting in a docker container there is a optional parameter

`--volume-driver string           Optional volume driver for the container`

What is the use of this parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Volume drivers let you store volumes on remote hosts or cloud providers, to encrypt the contents of volumes, or to add other functionality.

See [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-driver)

Comment: We may need the list of available drivers, which is kind of short https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/

Comment: @pdem Storage drivers are not the same as volume drivers. You linked to the list of storage drivers. A better list is here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/legacy_plugins/